# connect users to the sidechain SKALE

Tags: tokens, private-blockchain, metamask, sidechain

SKALE is Ethereum Dapps to run high speed, Low cost smart contract layer.

I wish to connect users to the sidechain SKALE,from their browser.
automatically without the manual change as necessary for metamask
with token attribuated in function of service utilisation

Comment: With Web3js you may connect to whatever node you want bypassing Web3 API implementation provided by the browser.

Comment: Is this can be implemented with normal web3js api

Answer (score 0):

You need to use WEb3js but bypass Web3 API provided by browser like this:

```js
const web3 = new Web3(/* Web3.givenProvider || */ 'ws://localhost:8546', null, {});
```

See [Web3js documentation](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/getting-started.html#adding-web3-js) for details.

Comment: Sure, but note that you'll lose the ability to sign transactions through Metamask by doing this.

Comment: Though it will be still possible to implement MEW-style client-side transaction signing.

Comment: I assumed OP wanted to use Metamask due to their mention, but I guess they didn't necessarily say that. I would only advise storing private keys in browser for accounts with very small value.

Answer (score 0):

A solution is to create a new private key and sign it with MetaMask and then register the new address with the contract in mainnet. This will create a relationship between the main account and the new private key.

Now every interaction with the sidechain can be done with the new private key, without having to sign every transaction with MetaMask.

If you store the new key in local storage then the next session you do not have to resign it with MetaMask reducing the interaction to a single registration the first time.